# Emulating A-Frame Daydream-Controls Component

Tags: aframe, webvr, daydream

A-Frame master branch now contains a [daydream-controls component](https://aframe.io/docs/master/components/daydream-controls.html), which I can get to work in my A-Frame project when I enter VR using my phone and daydream view HMD. However, I would like to emulate a daydream controller while developing, particularly to inspect event data, so I can develop the event handlers.

What would be the best strategy to generate event data for daydream-controls component during development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Motion Capture to automate controller development https://aframe.io/docs/0.5.0/introduction/visual-inspector-and-dev-tools.html#motion-capture